# Is there a Kummer theory for cyclic covers in higher dimension?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, kummer-theory

Let $d \geq 2$ be an integer and $K$ a field of characteristic zero containing the roots of unity of order $d$. Let $X$ be a smooth curve over $K$, not necessarily projective. Let $\overline{x}$ be a geometric point of $X$ and consider a non-trivial character 
$$
\chi: \pi_1(X, \overline{x}) \to \mu_d(\mathbb{C})
$$ of the algebraic fundamental group of $X$. Then $\ker(\chi)$ is a normal subgroup of $\pi_1(X, \bar{x})$ and corresponds to an étale cyclic cover $Y \to X$ with Galois group
$$
G=\pi_1(X, \overline{x})/ \ker(\chi). 
$$

If I understand correctly, Kummer theory says that there exists a rational function $f$ on $Y$ such that 
$$
f^\sigma=\chi(\sigma) f \quad (*)
$$ for each $\sigma \in G$. Then $f^d$ is a rational function on $X$.

Does anybody know a good reference for this statement? All the papers I have found just say "By Kummer theory..." (sometimes it's hard to learn classic mathematics for a beginner!)

My second question is how much of this story extends to higher dimension, that is, what happens if $\pi: Y \to X$ is a cyclic cover of a smooth higher dimensional variety $X$? Does there also exists a rational function on Y with the property (*)?

In the curve case, $Y$ is also smooth, but in general it will be only normal. I don't know if this is a problem.

Comment: This is called "Hilbert Theorem 90" and has nothing to do with curves. It just tells you that $H^1(G,K(Y)^*)$ is trivial, so any cocycle $\sigma \mapsto \chi (\sigma )$ is a coboundary $\sigma \mapsto f^{\sigma }/f$ for some $f\in K(Y)^*$.